# Are there different syntax/s for jquery callback function?

Tags: jquery, function, syntax, callback

I am used to using this syntax :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function(){
      $("button").click(function(){
           $("p").hide(1000,function(){
               alert("The paragraph is now hidden");
           });
      });
   });
</script>
```

but just lately I came across this one which works as well,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("a").hover(function(){
            $(this).stop().animate({ color: '#a6d13b'}, "normal");
        }, function() {
            $(this).stop().animate({ color: '#000000'}, "normal"); //original color
        });
    });
</script>
```

I'm just new to jquery and would really appreciate some help. why does the second syntax work ? even though its outside the animate function. ?

Comment: both scripts do really different things, please specify your question

Comment: The first uses a callback function to call the alert, the second uses two different events, mouseenter and mouseleave

Comment: I'm sorry for the confusion , I tried inserting a callback function to the second script,using the syntax from the first script. (which is the one I am used to using) as it turned out , the animation now is not functioning well.

my question is , is the syntax from the first script (which I'm used to following)  wrong ? if so , could you please provide me with the correct syntax ?

Comment: @MichaelPeterson: When binding to `hover`, 2 events are bound behind the scene `mouseover` and `mouseout`. Not `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`. See here for console output of the bound events after binding to `hover`: http://jsfiddle.net/qcMmT/

Comment: here is the code I came up with ,
    
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

    $("a").hover(function(){
    $(this).stop().animate({ color: '#a6d13b'}, "normal" , function() {
    $(this).stop().animate({ color: '#000000'}, "normal"); });
    });

         
    });
    </script>

Comment: @FrançoisWahl really? I thought it was mouseenter and mouseleave http://api.jquery.com/hover/

Comment: @MichaelPeterson: Going by the docs I would have thought so too until I saw the `data("events")` output. I linked a fiddle with the output in my other comment. The output is: `Object: mouseout: Array[1], mouseover: Array[1], __proto__: Object`

Comment: @FrançoisWahl huh, interesting. Strange, but interesting.

Comment: @MichaelPeterson: Seems though you can trigger `mouseleave` as well as `mouseout` ones `hover` is bound (as well as the other one). http://jsfiddle.net/5CY9k/1/ Reason for that is propably that the `mouseleave` and `mouseenter` events are custom and build on top of `mouseout` and `mouseover` but for some reason do not register in the `data("events")` object. So, yes you are correct off course, those custom events are bound was just confusing me that I could not find them in the data object.

Comment: @FrançoisWahl Thanks, I did not know that about the mouseleave and mouseenter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two scripts are doing completely different things, but (just guessing here) I think what is confusing you is that in the second script the `.hover()` function takes *two* callbacks as parameters, one for mouseenter and one for mouseleave, like this:

```
$("a").hover(callbackFunctionOne, callbackFunction2);
// OR
$("a").hover(function() { ... }, function() { ... });
```

In your example it is within these two functions passed to `.hover()` that the `.animate()` calls occur, but the `.animate()` calls themselves don't (in this case) have callbacks.

EDIT: Now that dknaack has edited your code to indent it properly it is more obvious that the `.animate()` calls are inside the two functions. When it wasn't indented it was much harder to see what belonged to what.

Note that `.animate()` (and many, many other jQuery functions) *can* take a callback, but this is optional.

Comment: I think this answer is pretty clear with some knowledge of JS, but OP seems a bit lost, so he'll probably get more confused, which is not bad tho.

Comment: Oh I see , Thank you for taking the time ! I guess one of the things that confused me was , I was not aware of the syntax of .hover() function as well. which is as explained $("a").hover(function() { ... }, function() { ... });

If it's not too much to ask , do you think you could suggest some sources as to where I can learn more about syntaxes of jquery events and functions ?

Comment: The "standard" syntax for most jQuery functions is for the callback (if a callback is allowed) to be the last parameter after any options. I'd strongly recommend spending an hour or more just reading through the summary of jQuery functions and selectors here: http://api.jquery.com/ - it has a one or two sentence summary of what each does, and you can click in for a detailed explanation of the ones you're more interested in. The detail pages for each method are pretty good, with explanations of parameters and example code.

Comment: P.S. To reiterate something I mentioned in my answer, if you make sure your code is nicely intended it is much easier to read and you're much less likely to get confused about what callback belongs to what method. If you need to read code that somebody else wrote that is messy you can format it using one of the online JS formatters like http://jspretty.com.